# update array state in react native

Tags: react-native, arraylist, state, setstate

I want to update the state of the array DataGameArr when I open screen but I still need to relaunch the application to see that the state changed even if I put the changement in the componentDidMount

How can I resolve this problem?

GameData.js :

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const data = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("GamesData")
      .child(this.props.email.key)
      .orderByChild("PlayDate")
      .once("value");

    const arrData = new Array();
    firebase.database().ref("GamesData").child(email.key).on("value", function (snapshot1) {
      snapshot1.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        arrData.push({ x: childSnapshot.val().PlayDate, y: childSnapshot.val().countPlay })
      })
      
    })

    this.setState({ DataGameArr: arrData })

  };
```

Answer (score 0):

ComponentDidMount is being called only when the component is the first time being inserted into tree (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), which happens at least with react-navigation at the first time screen is being opened.

If React Navigation is used this is the solution (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/).

A second possible solution would be to implement a interval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) where functionality is executed and screen would updated for example every 5 seconds.